# Jackson with JsonTypeInfo - Serialize Map with nested maps as values

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-serialization

In Java, I need to serialize an object that is wrapper for Map<String, Object>.
I would like to have a JsonTypeInfo for map values included in generated Json.

I have a problem when I put as value another map like Map<String, Object>.

The Code:

```
public class App3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, Object> fields = Map.of(
          "Key 1", new Date(),
          "Key2", Map.of("Key2_1", new Date()),
          "Key3", List.of(new Date())
        );

        MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer(fields);
        System.out.println(objectMapper().writeValueAsString(myContainer));
    }

    public static class MyContainer {

        @JsonProperty("fields")
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
        private Map<String, Object> fields;

        public MyContainer(Map<String, Object> fields) {
            this.fields = fields;
        }
    }

    public static ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
        objectMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
        objectMapper.setNodeFactory(JsonNodeFactory.withExactBigDecimals(true));

        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

This code generates Json as such:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Key3": [
            "java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12",
            [
                1612354278585
            ]
        ],
        "Key 1": [
            "java.util.Date",
            1612354278585
        ],
        "Key2": {
            "@class": "java.util.ImmutableCollections$Map1",
            "Key2_1": 1612354278585
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, Key3 and Key2 are missing "java.util.Date" type info since they are values from the nested map and nested list.

Is there a way to serialize this to Json to provide a type info for nested maps values similar as it is for Key 1.